# Hibernate - Query Works in MySQL WorkBench But Hibernate Throws SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My query works fine in workbench however hibernate throws the error `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'focusCategory' not found.` focusCategory is mapped correctly and it's not even part of the statements, I can't think of why this would be happening. The Focus table has not had any problems up until this point

Query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT F.focusID FROM Focus F " +
            "JOIN FrameworkFoci FF on FF.focusID = F.focusID " +
            "JOIN FocusGroups FG on FF.frameworkID = FG.frameworkID " +
            "JOIN GroupMembers GM on FG.groupID = GM.groupID " +
            "JOIN Users U on GM.userID = U.userID " +
            "WHERE U.userID = :userID", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Focus> findByUserID(@Param("userID") Long userID);
```

Focus Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Focus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long focusID;

    private String focusCategory;

    private String focusName;

    private String focusExplanation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "focus")
    private Set<Rating> ratings;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "FrameworkFoci",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "focusID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "frameworkID"))
    private Set<Framework> frameworks;

    protected Focus(){}

    public Focus(String focusName, String focusCategory, String focusExplanation) {
        this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
        this.focusName = focusName;
        this.focusExplanation = focusExplanation;
    }

    public Focus(String focusCategory, String focusName, String focusExplanation, Set<Rating> ratings){
        this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
        this.focusName = focusName;
        this.focusExplanation = focusExplanation;
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    public Long getFocusId() {
        return focusID;
    }

    public void setFocusId(Long focusID) {
        this.focusID = focusID;
    }

    public String getFocusCategory() {
        return focusCategory;
    }

    public void setFocusCategory(String focusCategory) {
        this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should give us more informations. By the way, porbably `focusCategory` is wrongly mapped.

Comment: It is correctly mapped, I have had no problems using the Focus entity up until now.

Comment: Might be clearer to use the [criteria api](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-criteria-api-in-expressions) to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Your native query returns in the `ResultSet` only one column `focusID` but you try to map it to the `Focus` entity. I do not see in this sql any reason why you should use here native sql. So, more preferable way as for me here is [hql or jpql](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql).

The following query will work as you expected:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT F.focusID FROM Focus F " +
      "JOIN FrameworkFoci FF on FF.focusID = F.focusID " +
      "JOIN FocusGroups FG on FF.frameworkID = FG.frameworkID " +
      "JOIN GroupMembers GM on FG.groupID = GM.groupID " +
      "JOIN Users U on GM.userID = U.userID " +
      "WHERE U.userID = :userID", nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> findByUserID(@Param("userID") Long userID);
```